# VBScript в Statistica

Tags: vbscript, статистика

Хочу вывести значения массива в Statistica VB, но получаю такую ошибку: "Должен быть массив созданный операцией Dim". Что я делаю не так?
[image: error_statistica]

Comment: `Call MATRIXDISPLAY(AnArray(),"Spreadsheet Title")`

Comment: не работает, та же ошибка